# How to redirect without changing URL .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a button in my view:

```
<td>
  <button id="btn" class="button btn-primary" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RunAll", new { id = @id })'"> Run Test</button>
  <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" style="display:none;" />
</td>
```

WHich calls method in my HomeController:

```
  public IActionResult RunAll(int id) {
        _service.RunAll(id);
        var items = _service.GetAllTests<MyClass>();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

After executing this method I want to be redirected to the same page I am (localhost:5000) but when I run my app un linux server URL changes to http://localhost:5000/Home/RunAllTests/374 on windows it works fine. Is there any workaround or fix for that?

Comment: Have you tried using an anchor tag instead of a button?

Comment: Yes and the same problem.... works on windows but doesn't on linux

Comment: What I should have asked is have you tried it as a normal link and not using the `onclick="..."` event?  I can't understand why you're manually setting the location like that.

Comment: How do I call method this way then?

Comment: Is there a mismatch between `RunAll` and `RunAllTests`? To check whether it is related with other part, if you create a new simple Core app to test `RedirectToAction`, will you receive the same error? Do you receive any error in `_service.RunAll(id);
        var items = _service.GetAllTests<MyClass>();`? If you comment out this line and on test with `return RedirectToAction("Index");`, will this issue exist?

Answer (score -1):

If you use .net core then you can easily call anchor tag in view like this below:

```
    @model YourModel
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <a asp-controller="Home"
       asp-action="RunAll" 
       asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Run Test</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In controller your code would be like:

```
[Route("Home/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult RunAll(int id) {
    _service.RunAll(id);
    var items = _service.GetAllTests<MyClass>();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In Startup.configure you might have default route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{

 // default route 
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```